# docker swarm: how to publish a service only on a specific node that runs a task

Tags: docker, port, docker-swarm

I created a `docker-compose.yml` file containing two services that are run on two different nodes. The two services are meant to communicate on the same port as client and server. Below is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
 version: "3"
services:
  service1:
    image: localrepo/image1
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == node1]
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1000M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - webnet

  service2:
    image: localrepo/image2
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == node2]
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 500M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

When I issue `docker stack deploy -c` I get error, reading

```
> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = port '8000' is already in use by service.
```

In this [thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33160) I read that deploying a service in a swarm makes the port accessible throughout any node in the swarm.  If I understand correctly, that makes the port occupied by any node in the cluster. In the same thread, it was suggested to use `mode=host` publishing, which will only expose the port on the actual host that the container runs. I applied that in the port as:

ports:
  - "mode=host, target=8000, published=8000"

Making that change in both service and trying to issue docker stack gives another error:

```
> 1 error(s) decoding:

* Invalid containerPort: mode=host, target=8000, published=8000
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

p.s: I tried both "Version3" and "Version3.2" but the issue didn't solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how did you specify `host mode` since your `docker-compose.yml` doesn't represent `host mode` anywhere.

Incidentally, try with [long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1) which can specify `host mode` in `docker-compose.yml` file.

This long syntax is new in `v3.2` and the below is the example(I check it works)

([This](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix) is compatible `docker engine` version against `docker-compose` syntax version.)

```
version: '3.4'     # version: '3.2' also will works

networks:
    swarm_network:
        driver: overlay


services:
    service1:
        image: asleea/test

        command: ["nc", "-vlkp", "8000"]

        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.hostname == node1

        ports:
            - published: 8000
              target: 8000
              mode: host

        networks:
            swarm_network:

    service2:
        image: asleea/test

        command: ["nc", "service1", "8000"]

        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.hostname == node2

        ports:
            - published: 8000
              target: 8000
              mode: host

        networks:
            swarm_network:
```

Comment: I tried your code.  'version: 3.4" was giving me error: `unsupported Compose file version: 3.4`. I then tried with version 3.2 and I got an error: `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = port '8000' is already in use by service 'myapp_camera' (uyzczu7of5982qranrxpnjh3q)`. In my `docker-compose.yml`, I do not have the command. The client & server python applications are encapsulated inside the images.  I also copy pasted your code and tried to run it in version 3.2 and the same error happens that the port is already occupied by the first created service. Any idea?

Comment: There already seems to be another service using port `8000`, remove the service first `$ docker service rm myapp_camera` and to make sure, check if there is some process using the port at each node `$ ss -nlp | grep 8000`.

Comment: I did all. There is no process/service using the port at all the nodes, but it still shows the problem.

Comment: Then, what is `myapp_camera`? have you ever tried to run the service `myapp_camera`? I don't understand, docker is specifying clearly which service and even service ID is using the port. 

How about other ports, not `8000`?

Comment: the `myapp_camera` is the service name for my `service2` (I changed it to suit the task running in the service). I will map the port to something different and see what happens:

Comment: otherwise, try with the latest version of docker. there was the similar [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31249) and it seemed to be fixed.

Comment: I am not sure if it has to do with my docker version or the Compose version. I took your `docker-compose.yml` file, changed all the `8000` port number to `9000` and run it. The same error pops out again: `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = port '9000' is already in use by service 'test_service1' (a687tuh1cfaaw6sv1o1c3q6mi)`.

Comment: I will try to do that. Does it require to upgrade docker in all my nodes or is it just enough to upgrade the manager node in my cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed after upgrading to the latest docker version, `18.01.0-ce`